# can we support IBL for obj-mtl/FBX Loader for three js

Tags: three.js, fbx, objloader

ThreeJs obj-mtl/fbx loader uses default MeshPhongMaterial, which does not support IBL. To support IBL we had to change materials at the time of loading. Can we do changes in the library itself to use `MeshStandardMaterial` or `MeshPhysicalMaterial` for obj-mtl/fbx loader ???

Comment: I'm afraid your formulation is not correct here. `MeshPhongMaterial` just not supports the output of `PMREMGenerator`. You can still apply environment maps to it which are a form of IBL. In any event, it does probably not make sense to default the material of `OBJLoader` and `FBXLoader` to a PBR material since unlike glTF, the respective 3D standards do no support a PBR workflow.

Comment: not default but like an option.

Comment: to render the obj/fbx, we have to change MeshPhong to PBR material at the run time, other wise it wont render.

Comment: Sorry, this is something that has to manage the application.

Comment: I think OBJLoader is no longer getting much attention because the file format is a bit antiquated when compared to GLTF. GLTFLoader is getting lots of new features and attention, including IBL material support. If you don't want to manually override the materials via code, I recommend you export your assets in GLTF, there are exporters available for lots of different 3D editing tools.